# Print all sub-sequences of a string using backtracking recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I know that's a question that has been asked here a lot, and there is plenty of examples online, but I didn't found one that matches my question.

---

I need to write a code that will receive a string and will print all the different sub-sequences in the order they appear in the word. The solution should have recursive method(s) only, with no loops at all.
(should be based on backtracking recursion and arrays or substrings only, apparently)

> For example '012' should print:  "0", "1", "2", "01", "12", "02",
>   "012"

at first i was going for something like this:

```
public static void printSubs(String s) {
    printSubsSol(s, "");
}

private static void printSubsSol(String s, String temp) {
    if (s.length()==0) {
        System.out.print(temp+" ");
        return;
    }
    printSubsSol(s.substring(1), temp);
    printSubsSol(s.substring(1),temp+s.charAt(0));
}
```

> Prints: 2 1 12 0 02 01 012

I wasn't able to print all the sub-sequences in the right order, so now I tried a different approach using a char array, which with I had a bit more success bum I'm not there yet

```
public class Ex9Q2V4 {
public static void printSubs(String s) {
    char[] tempArr = new char[s.length() - 1];
    printSubsSol(s, 0, 0, tempArr, 1);
    System.out.println('"' + s + '"');
}

private static boolean isSafe(int arrayIndex, int currentIndex, int howMuchToPrint, int length) {
    return (arrayIndex < howMuchToPrint && arrayIndex <= currentIndex && currentIndex < length);
}

private static void printSubsSol(String s, int arrayIndex, int currentIndex, char[] charArr, int howMuchToPrint) {
    if (howMuchToPrint == s.length()) {
        return;
    }
    charArr[arrayIndex] = s.charAt(currentIndex);
    if (arrayIndex == howMuchToPrint - 1) {
        System.out.print("\"");
        printArray(charArr, howMuchToPrint);
        System.out.print("\"" + ", ");
    }
    if (isSafe(arrayIndex + 1, currentIndex + 1, howMuchToPrint, s.length())) {
        printSubsSol(s, arrayIndex + 1, currentIndex + 1, charArr, howMuchToPrint);

    }
    else if (isSafe(arrayIndex, currentIndex + 1, howMuchToPrint, s.length())) {
        printSubsSol(s, arrayIndex, currentIndex + 1, charArr, howMuchToPrint);

    }
    else printSubsSol(s, 0, 0, charArr, howMuchToPrint + 1);
}

// A method that prints the array
private static void printArray(char arr[], int n) {
    if (n != 0) {
        printArray(arr, n - 1);
        System.out.print(arr[n - 1]);
    }
}
```

}

> Prints: "0", "1", "2", "01", "02", "12", "012"

If possible, I will love to see the solution in both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an algorithm in `C` online and converted it to `Java` and to use `Strings`.  You can see the article [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generating-all-possible-subsequences-using-recursion/)

I had to store the values in a `TreeSet` to get the desired order.

Here is how to call it.

```
        String str = "0123";

        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator
                .comparing(String::length)
                .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));

        subseq(str, 0, "", set);

        set.forEach(System.out::println);
```

And here is the modified algorithm.

```
    static void subseq(String arr, int index, String subarr,
            Set<String> set) {
        if (index == arr.length()) {
            int l = subarr.length();
            if (l != 0) {
                set.add(subarr.substring(0, l));
            }
        } else {
            subseq(arr, index + 1, subarr, set);
            subarr = subarr
                    + arr.substring(index, index + 1);
            subseq(arr, index + 1, subarr, set);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but same as the previous answer,  your solution doesn't print "02". It will only print chars that are next to each other. 
At first I also started with a pencil and paper, and only afterwards I moved to code, but even on the paper I  wasn't able to think about the right algorithm to do it *in this specific order*

Comment: You're right!  I fixed it.  But I had to add the values to a `TreeSet` to get the order.

Comment: Thank you again, but I'm not supposed to use Tree's so I'll wait for some more answers

Comment: Perhaps you should update  your answer and be explicit about what you may and may not use.  Otherwise, folks will just be guessing.  You never said you couldn't use a Set.

Comment: I'm allowed to use a set, but I know I'm not supposed to use it. So I want to see other solutions. The one thing that was specificed  in the question was loops, and I mantion it, but I will edit. Than you again anyway

Answer (score 0):

Let's see with a loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j + i <= s.length(); j++) {
          System.out.print(s.substring(j, j + i) + " ");
     }
}
```

You're on the right track with your second idea, you need an index and a length but it seems overcomplicated.

```
static void print(String s, int start, int length) {
    System.out.print(s.substring(start, start + length) + " ");
    if (start + length < s.length())
        print(s, start + 1, length);
    else if (length < s.length())
        print(s, 0, length + 1);
}
```

First we print the substring.

The if condition is the nested loop, if the start index + the length to print is still inferior to the length of the string, we just increment the start index

The else part is the first loop, when you've reached the end of the input string and cannot substring anymore, you set the start index back to 0 and increment the length. If the length is equal to the length of the input, recursion stops

Of course you should first check if the input is not empty

Comment: Thank you, but your solution doesn't print "02". It will only print chars that are next to each other.

Comment: You're right, i didn't pay enough attention, could you tell me what it's supposed to print for "0123" so i can edit my answer ?

Comment: “0”, “1”, “2”, “3”, “01”, “12”, “23”, “02”, “03”, “13”, “012”, “123”, “023”, “013”, “0123”